# JS get length of words separated by comma + last word

Tags: javascript

I have an input with this string

```
one, two, three
```

I'm getting the total number of words separated by comma:

```
val = $("input").val().replace(" ", "");
words = val.split(",");
count = words.length;
```

It returns 2 but there is one more word `three`. There is no comma after it so it is not being split/counted.

How can I include the last word in the length?

Also what if I have a single word with no comma after it?

```
one
```

It should return 1.

Note: I'm getting the word length live from the input as I type, using `keyup, keypress`. Not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: At least in your example, you're declaring `val` and then operating on `value`. Is that a typo, or the bug?

Comment: `one, two, three`.split(',').length` this returns desired output, moreover as you're just taking length, so why replacing `space` ?

Comment: @BenSteward it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let str = 'one, two, three'
console.log( !str ? 0 : str.split(',').length )
```

Comment: You should elaborate on what you've changed.

Comment: Good catch! Adding that 0 helped

Comment: Always check for empty strings, I learned it the hard way ahaha

Answer (score 1):

I have tested this in the below code and it functions correctly.

Can you provide a jsFiddle with you example working incorrectly?

```js
function getCount(string) {
    val = string.replace(" ", "");
    words = val.split(",");
    count = words.length;
    console.log(count);
}

getCount('one');
getCount('one, two, three')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It may be happening when i have just 1 word without the comma

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.split()` instead like this:

```js
let str = "one, two, three";

console.log(str.split(',').length);

let word = "one";

console.log(word.split(',').length);
```